# Javascript/AJAX reload the file only "onchange"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have this script, which reloads a file every 3 seconds.
I need this to work in another way, so it loads a file, only if it is changed.

```
function loadLog(){     
    $.ajax({
        url: "peoplechatlololol.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
                     $("#chatbox").html(html);
                 },
        });
    } setInterval (loadLog, 3000);
```

This is just not normal to load a file every 3 seconds.

Here is what I need (somehow):

```
 function loadLog(){        
        $.ajax({
            url: "peoplechatlololol.html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                         //now my fantasy takes place
                         if "peoplechatlololol.html" changed (or check the size of recent file) {
                              $("#chatbox").html(html);
                         }
                         else "Do not load the file into #chatbox"
                     },
            });
        } setInterval (loadLog, 3000);
```

Comment: Just trying to find a way to make this work properly, but no success in it for now. Just learning JS.

Comment: should we repeat the question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I just started to learn JS, what do you want from me?

Comment: The other people are asking what have you tried to fix your problem? Loading a page every three seconds is not ideal, but the only real alternative is to use a websocket, requiring changes on the server

Comment: Somehow I need to find a way to check if "peoplechatlololol.html" is changed from the first load time, and reload it. But not reload the file every 3 secs.

Comment: Two operations are happening here: (1) you load the file from the server, and (2) you display the contents in the `#chatbox` element. If you mean you don't want to run (2) unless there were changes, then you want a `var lastHtml;` ABOVE (outside) the `loadLog` function, then inside the success handler you can say `if (html === lastHtml) { ... }`. Followed by `lastHtml = html;` to set `lastHtml` for next time. If you mean you don't want to run (1) unless there are changes (you don't want to speak to the server every 3 secs unnecessarily) – that's a more difficult topic. Which are you after?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call setinterval method with $(document).ready(function(){  });. In place of setinterval method, try to use setTimeout method.

Answer (score 0):

well i guess that you used all these codes as a function and calling it while textbox or other thing changed. actually `onchange="..."` attribute.

have you tried this jquery code?

```
function loadLog(){     
   $.ajax({
    url: "peoplechatlololol.html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){        
                 $("#chatbox").html(html);
             },
    });
}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var appTimer = setInterval (loadLog, 3000);
});
</script>
```

i dont haven't seen your entire source but i think this could solve your problem.
and dont forget to remove setInterval thing from your onchange attributes. it makes it worst.